# Returning JSON in ASP.NET controller method

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following working controller method, which returns the JSON in a simple text format.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DecodeBarcode(string productCodeScheme, string productCode, string serialNumber, string batch, string expirationDate, int commandStatusCode) {
    string TextAreaResult = string.Empty;
    try {
        TextAreaResult = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", request.getHttpInformation(), request.getHttpWarning(), request.getHttpResponseCode());
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        TextAreaResult = "Exception: " + exc.Message;
    }
    return Json(TextAreaResult);
}
```

The output after the above method is run looks something like

```
"The pack is active No warning 200"
```

whereas

```
request.getHttpInformation() is The pack is active
request.getHttpWarning() is No warning
request.getHttpResponseCode() is 200
```

Now, I am trying to split the response into 3 different key-value pairs so that my response will look like

```
{
  httpInformation: "The pack is active",
  httpWarning: "No Warning",
  httpResponseCode: "200"
}
```

How do I pass the additional params in `return Json(TextAreaResult)` call?

If I do like the following it won't work

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DecodeBarcode(string productCodeScheme, string productCode, string serialNumber, string batch, string expirationDate, int commandStatusCode) {
    string TextAreaResult = string.Empty;
    string TextAreaResultHttpInformation = string.Empty;
    string TextAreaResultHttpWarning = string.Empty;
    string TextAreaResultHttpResponseCode = string.Empty;

    try {
        TextAreaResultHttpInformation = string.Format("{0}}", request.getHttpInformation());

        TextAreaResultHttpWarning = string.Format("{1}}", request.getHttpWarning());

        TextAreaResultHttpResponseCode = string.Format("{2}}", request.getHttpResponseCode());
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        TextAreaResult = "Exception: " + exc.Message;
    }

    return Json(TextAreaResultHttpInformation, TextAreaResultHttpInformation, TextAreaResultHttpResponseCode);
}
```

How do I construct the key-value pairs and return as JSON? Perhaps, `Json` method is not the right choice over here, but being new to C#, I am not aware of any other c# inbuilt methods for constructing JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you actually want to consume the response as JSON, you could achieve this by doing

```
return Json(new 
{
    HttpInformation = TextAreaResultHttpInformation, 
    HttpWarning = TextAreaResultHttpWarning,
    StatusCode = TextAreaResultHttpResponseCode
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make wrapper class for these properties and return it.

```
public class BarcodeResultDto
    {
        [JsonProperty("httpInformation")]
        public string HttpInformation { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("httpWarning")]
        public string HttpWarning { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("httpResponseCode")]
        public int GetHttpResponseCode { get; set; }
    }

public IActionResult DecodeBarcode(string productCodeScheme, string productCode, string serialNumber,
            string batch, string expirationDate, int commandStatusCode)
        {
            var barcodeResult = new BarcodeResultDto
            {
                GetHttpResponseCode = 200,
                HttpInformation = "The pack is active",
                HttpWarning = "No Warning"
            };

            // your code here
            return Ok(barcodeResult);
        }
```

Or you can change retuned value from IActionResult to JsonResult

Answer (score -1):

If you want a different approach then you can use JsonSerializer in the following way :

```
// Creating BlogSites object  
BlogSites bsObj = new BlogSites()  
{  
   Name = "test-name",  
   Description = "test-description"  
};  

// Serializing object to json data  
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();  
string jsonData = js.Serialize(bsObj); // {"Name":"test-name","Description":"test-description"}
```

You will just need to create a class and store value in its objects then serialize it. If you have a list then you can use List of that class and then serialize.